# In firestore "Property 'arrayUnion' does not exist on type 'typeof FieldValue'"

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I am using @angular/fire": "7.4.0" in my angular project where I just want to do update operation on User document. In user document there is a field 'groups' which is of type of array in firestore. I want to insert a new value inside that array. [Check Image for user document structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjmER.png)

I am using the following syntax for update operation-

```
//Add Group in user's groups array
  addGroupToUserDoc(gid: string, userId: string) {
    const userRef = this.db.doc(`users/${userId}`).update(
      {
        groups: FieldValue.arrayUnion(gid),
        
      }
    );
  }
```

error - [error received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCCc3.png)

here this.db is 'AngularFirestore' object. I referred the following two resources and tried both ways but nothing worked.

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2008

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Answer (score 1):

In my case using SDK in Node environment I had to use

`import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'`

`admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(gid)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "firestore" before FieldValue. Like so:

```
//Add Group in user's groups array
  addGroupToUserDoc(gid: string, userId: string) {
    const userRef = this.db.doc(`users/${userId}`).update(
      {
        groups: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(gid),
        
      }
    );
  }
```

and import the firestore from firestore/app

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
```